# material-ui connect by CDN failure

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am new to material-ui , i have tried to use it by CDN link .
But the following error shows. anyone help?

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.sheetsManager.set is not a function
    at r.value (unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@3.0.1/umd/material-ui.production.min.js:6)
    at new r (unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@3.0.1/umd/material-ui.production.min.js:6)
    at react-dom.js:4756
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (react-dom.js:4537)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (react-dom.js:4755)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (react-dom.js:4741)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4649)
    at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11551)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react-dom.js:4832)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4719)
```

**CDN**

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**JS**

```
var Button2 = window['material-ui'].Button;
console.log(window['material-ui'].Button);
```

Comment: I saw your questions, you're getting errors because of `CDN` , what's the point of using it if you're getting errors.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke actually, a CDN is much more easier to use than unnecessarily struggling with npm packages and setting up webpack

Comment: @HenriqueHBR by using create-react-app, I don't think he has to set up webpack manually.